# NHibernate Configuration Settings

Tags: nhibernate

This is my Configuration file. I have a database that name is Basin.
 My sql server editon is 2012 express.
also, My Project name is NHibernate_Test

```
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
  <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
  <propert name="query.substitutions">hqlFunction=SQLFUNC</propert>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
  <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Basin; Integrated Security=True; </property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping assembly="NHibernate_Test"/>
</session-factory>   </hibernate-configuration> </configuration
```

But I am getting a error

Error : An exception occurred parsing configuration :The element 'session-factory' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2' has invalid child element 'propert' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2'. List of possible elements expected: 'property, mapping, class-cache, collection-cache, event, listener' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2'.

Comment: Reading and understanding error messages 101:  read the error message, read it thoroughly and understand what it is saying.  Then check your code against the error message ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is at the line:

```
<propert name="query.substitutions">hqlFunction=SQLFUNC</propert>
```

exactly as in the exception:

> ..has invalid child element **'propert'** in namespace..

we need

```
<property...
```

see the **property** with **y** at the end